# Syncing Data and Coordinate Scripts Across Machines

Tags: command-line

I have Ubuntu installed on several laptops and I was wondering if it was possible to synchronize the data on them (from one device) AND also run one script/command on all of them from one device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. But first, you may want to define which data you want to sync. You can write a simple bash script that copies all the desired files from one computer to another (you should consider using SSH-keys to avoid entering the user's password every time that you want to coy files).
My approach would be to have a menu with the option "copy data from". You can list the laptops/PC's and select the one that is going to update the rest.

Please note that you can also use any cloud solution like dropbox/drive, etc. to sync both personal and config files.

Answer (score 0):

For data synchronization, you should take a look at `rsync`. Running scripts will require setting up SSH on the laptops, then you need to log in on them, and run the scripts on each machine.